# Split a string using numerals as delimiter in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

`120h2m12s` => `120h 2m 12s`

`120a2b12c` => `120a 2b 12c`

I want to split whenever a number appears after a non-number.

How can I achieve this in bash?

**Here is what I tried so far:**

- `$ echo "120h2m12s" | sed 's/[hm]/& /g'`
  => 120h 2m 12s (kind of works, but I would prefer a more generally applicable solution. A way to split a string using numerals as delimiter.)

Comment: It is always advised to post your efforts in your post what you have tried so far, kindly do so.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 I added a "What I have tried so far" section. If I find a better solution I will update this accordingly.

Comment: You don't treat numerals as a delimiter in your example.

Comment: Hi @Lino this works when we assume we are dealing only w/ h, m, s. But I want a more generally applicable solution. Whenever a number appears after a non-number split it. Do you know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo '120h2m12s' | sed 's/[0-9]*/ &/g'
 120h 2m 12s
```

You end up with a leading space using the above, if that matters then:

```
$ echo '120h2m12s' | sed 's/\([^0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1 \2/g'
120h 2m 12s
```

Comment: Yes you are correct this answer the question best. Thank you

Comment: or  `sed 's/[^0-9]\+/& /g'` which introduces an extra space at the end.

Comment: Compare `<<<'abc'  sed 's/[0-9]*/ &/g'` to  `<<<'abc'  sed 's/[0-9]\+/ &/g'`

Comment: I know but that's not what the OPs input looks like so I'd rather keep it simple and portable to all seds and work for the input he has than make it specific to GNU sed (or even make it work for GNU and OSX/BSD sed with `sed -E 's/[0-9]+/ &/g'` or even keep it portable but more complicated with `sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/ &/g'`) just to cover a case he doesn't actually have.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following too:

```
echo "120h2m12s" | sed 's/[0-9]*[a-z]*/& /g'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
120h 2m 12s
```

Check with another self made dummy example too:

```
echo "120h2m12s12131313ddd" | sed 's/[0-9]*[a-z]*/& /g'
120h 2m 12s 12131313ddd
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "120h2m12s" | sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\([0-9]\)/\1 \2/g'`

Adds a space in between when it sees a letter followed by a digit.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd use perl, it's very succinct:

```
echo "$time" | perl -pe 's/(\D)(\d)/$1 $2/g'
```

But if you want bash:

```
$ echo "$time";
120h2m12s

$ while [[ $time =~ ([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]]+) ]]; do 
    time=${time/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}}
done

$ echo "$time"
120h 2m 12s
```